# Rails: Belongs_to and Has_many associations in Rails Engines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-engines

So I building an application using **Rails 6**. I have implemented some core features of the app using **Rails Engines**.

The name of the Engine **Baseblog**, and I have 2 models for it called **Author** and **Post**.

An `author` has many `posts`, while a `post` belongs to one `author`. Below are my model implementations:

**Author Model**:

```
module Baseblog
  class Author < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy

    validates :name, presence: true
    validates :address, presence: true
  end
end
```

**Post Model**:

```
module Baseblog
  class Post < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :author

    validates :name, presence: true
  end
end
```

Here's my rspec test for the **Author** model:

**Author Spec**

```
require 'rails_helper'

module Baseblog
  RSpec.describe Author, type: :model do
    describe 'associations' do
      it { is_expected.to have_many(:posts) }
    end

    describe "validations" do
      it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of(:name) }
      it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of(:address) }
    end
  end
end
```

**Author Factory Bot**

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :school do
    name { "MyString" }
    address { "MyText" }
  end
end
```

**Schema for Posts**

```
create_table "baseblog_posts", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "name"
  t.text "description"
  t.bigint "baseblog_author_id", null: false
  t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  t.index ["baseblog_author_id"], name: "index_baseblog_posts_on_baseblog_author_id"
  end
```

However, when I run my test for the Author model, I get the error:

```
Failures:

  1) Baseblog::Author associations is expected to have many posts
     Failure/Error: it { is_expected.to have_many(:posts) }
       Expected Baseblog::Author to have a has_many association called posts (Baseblog::Post does not have a author_id foreign key.)
     # ./spec/models/baseblog/author_spec.rb:6:in `block (3 levels) in <module:Baseblog>'

Finished in 0.29222 seconds (files took 2.9 seconds to load)
6 examples, 1 failure
```

How do I define the has_many and belongs_to association between the **Author** model and the **Post** model? Any form of assistance will be highly appreciated.

**Update**:

The test spec for the **Author** model passes now after I modified it following way using [dedypuji's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66239584/10907864):

**Author Model**

```
module Baseblog
  class Author < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :posts, class_name: 'Baseblog::Post', foreign_key: :baseblog_author_id, dependent: :destroy

    validates :name, presence: true
    validates :address, presence: true
  end
end
```

**Post Model**

```
module Baseblog
  class Post < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :author, class_name: 'Baseblog::Author', foreign_key: :baseblog_author_id

    validates :name, presence: true
  end
end
```

However, the spec test for Post model still fails:

**Post Spec**

require 'rails_helper'

module Baseblog
RSpec.describe Post, type: :model do
describe 'associations' do
it { is_expected.to belong_to(:author) }
end

```
describe 'validations' do
  it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of(:name) }
  it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of(:author_id) }
end
```

end
end

**Factory Bot for Post spec**

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :post do
    name { "MyString" }

    association :author
  end
end
```

However, when I run the spec test for **Post** I get the error below:

```
Failures:

  1) Baseblog::Post associations is expected to belong to author required: true
     Failure/Error: it { is_expected.to belong_to(:author) }
     
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `author_id' for #<Baseblog::Post:0x000056397e47dc50>
       Did you mean?  author
                      author=
     # ./spec/models/baseblog/post_spec.rb:6:in `block (3 levels) in <module:Baseblog>'

Baseblog::Post validations is expected to validate that :author_id cannot be empty/falsy
     Failure/Error: it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of(:author_id) }
     
     Shoulda::Matchers::ActiveModel::AllowValueMatcher::AttributeDoesNotExistError:
       The matcher attempted to set :author_id on the Baseblog::Post to
       nil, but that attribute does not exist.
     # ./spec/models/baseblog/post_spec.rb:19:in `block (3 levels) in <module:Baseblog>'
```

Comment: do you have author_id in Baseblog::Post in your schema?

Comment: Yes. I just added it to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you try this?

```rb
module Baseblog
  class Author < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :posts, class_name: 'Baseblog::Post', foreign_key: :baseblog_author_id, dependent: :destroy

    validates :name, presence: true
    validates :address, presence: true
  end
end
```

```rb
module Baseblog
  class Post < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :author, class_name: 'Baseblog::Author', foreign_key: :baseblog_author_id

    validates :name, presence: true
  end
end
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you so much. I think a thing to note here is that the `foreign_key` for the **Author** model and the **Post** model is the same.

Comment: yeah i had the same issue though, i did that way because maybe rails have to specify class name and foreign key for model in a module. maybe you can find some better solution

Comment: I encountered some other issues when testing and I have updated the question @dedypuji, can you assist?

Comment: use baseblog_author_id instead using author_id if you assign directly by using id, or you can assign using author association if you use BaseBlog::Author instance